# function with lots of if else's blocks. Can these be removed

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function that needs to check a datetime against a supplied datetime. My function is shown below (it works fine however I don't like it). The only thing that needs to change is the operator but currently I have a few if, else if's etc & lines of code that have been copied.

I'm sure I'm being stupid and there is a much better way of doing this?

```
 enum DateTimeOperator
 {
        Equals = 0, GreaterThanOrEqualTo, GreaterThan, LessThan
 }
```

My function

```
 bool DateChecked(DateTime dateCheck DateTimeOperator dateOperator)
 {
       if(dateOperator == DateTimeOperator.Equals)
       {
           if (File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath + fileName).Date == dateCheck .Date)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
       }
       else if(dateOperator == DateTimeOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo)
       {
           if (File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath + fileName).Date >= dateCheck .Date)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
       }
       else if(dateOperator == DateTimeOperator.LessThan)
       {
           if (File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath + fileName).Date < dateCheck .Date)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
       }
 }
```

Comment: Can replace `if` with `switch`...

Comment: you can replace outer `if`s with `switch`. since condition is an `enum`, VS will create `case`s for you as well. In addition, you may replace inner `if`s with ternary operators: `return File.GetLastWriteTime(...).Date == dateCheck.Date ? true : false` or direct comparison `return File.GetLastWriteTime(...).Date == dateCheck.Date;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest an *extension method*: you have no need to put any `switch` or `if` whenever you want to compare dates using `DateTimeOperator`:

```
  public static class DateTimeOperatorExtensions {
    public static Func<Boolean, DateTime, DateTime> Comparison(this DateTimeOperator operation) {
      switch(operation) {
        //TODO: implenent other cases: i.e. DateTimeOperator.NotEquals here
        DateTimeOperator.Equals:
          return (left, right) => left == right;
        DateTimeOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
          return (left, right) => left >= right;  
        DateTimeOperator.LessThan:
          return (left, right) => left < right;   
        default: 
          return (left, right) => left == right; 
      }
    }
  }

  ...

  bool DateChecked(DateTime dateCheck DateTimeOperator dateOperator) {
    return dateOperator.Comparison()(dateCheck, File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath + fileName).Date);
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message saying No overload for method Comparison that takes two arguements? I changed the Func<Boolean, DateTime, DateTime> to Func<DateTime, DateTime, Boolean>

Comment: @mHelpMe: I'm sorry for the typo: is should be `Comparison()` (note "()") and only then `(dateCheck...`

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun without `if`/`switch`:

```
Dictionary<DateTimeOperator, Func<DateTime, DateTime, bool>> operatorComparer = new Dictionary<DateTimeOperator, Func<DateTime, DateTime, bool>>
{
    { DateTimeOperator.Equals, (a, b) => a == b },
    { DateTimeOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo, (a, b) => a >= b },
    { DateTimeOperator.GreaterThan, (a, b) => a > b },
    { DateTimeOperator.LessThan, (a, b) => a < b }
};

bool DateChecked(DateTime dateCheck, DateTimeOperator dateOperator)
{
   //TODO: add a sanity check
   return operatorComparer[dateOperator](File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath + fileName).Date, dateCheck .Date);
}
```

Comment: Definitely like the creativity on this one!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of the above code, which I believe to be simpler and more readable

```
bool DateChecked(DateTime dateCheck DateTimeOperator dateOperator)
{
    var result = false;
    var myDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath + fileName).Date;

    switch(dateOperator)
    {
        case DateTimeOperator.Equals:
            result = myDate == dateCheck.Date;
            break;
        case DateTimeOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
            result = myDate >= dateCheck.Date;
            break;
        case DateTimeOperator.LessThan:
            result =  myDate < dateCheck.Date;
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

or if you don't like the one return statement

```
bool DateChecked(DateTime dateCheck DateTimeOperator dateOperator)
{
    var myDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(filePath + fileName).Date;
    switch(dateOperator)
    {
        case DateTimeOperator.Equals:
            return myDate == dateCheck.Date;
        case DateTimeOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo:
            return myDate >= dateCheck.Date;
        case DateTimeOperator.LessThan:
            return myDate < dateCheck.Date;
    }
}
```